# Array sorting doesn't work the way it should be

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array,but it doesn't work the way I want to.

My code is as follows.

```
<?php
$classroom = array("4/10","4/2","4/1","4/11","5/2","1/2","5/1","5/10","5/12");
sort($classroom);
print_r($classroom);
?>
```

The result is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1/2 [1] => 4/1 [2] => 4/10 [3] => 4/11 [4] => 4/2 [5] => 5/1 [6] => 5/10 [7] => 5/12 [8] => 5/2 )
```

I would like to sort it to be:

```
 1/2,4/1,4/2,4/10,4/11,5/1,5/2,5/10,5/12
```

I'm quite new to sort functions. Would you please give me an example of using usort?

Comment: You can use usort() to control how the array is to be sorted with your own function. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coincidentally `natsort` seems to work:

```
<?php

$classroom = array("4/10","4/2","4/1","4/11","5/2","1/2","5/1","5/10","5/12");

natsort($classroom);
print_r($classroom);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1/2
    [1] => 4/1
    [4] => 4/2
    [2] => 4/10
    [3] => 4/11
    [5] => 5/1
    [8] => 5/2
    [6] => 5/10
    [7] => 5/12
)
```

Full disclosure: I'm not 100% sure it would work for all use cases, I haven't tested it. Use with caution.

Comment: Wow didn't know PHP has that function. :)

Comment: This sorting function works fine in my case. Thank you so much for your reply. And I have just learnt a new function.

Comment: It's surprising that `natsort` is not as well known as the other sort functions, but it's true, I didn't know it existed for years of developing PHP. As a trivia, you can also use `sort($array, SORT_NATURAL)` to achieve the same result (`sort` with flags is another less known functionality).

Comment: I can't seem to see the difference of these two sorting functions,natsort and SORT_NATURAL, will natsort be deprecated in the future?

Comment: @Wasinha I doubt it, but yes they work identically. The difference is you can use `SORT_NATURAL` with `ksort` and `asort` as well while `natsort` only sorts values and does not preserve keys.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are comparing **strings** in your `sort()` function. You should first *convert* your fraction string to **float** values before comparing them:

```
function fracstr_to_float($str)    {
    $num = intval(explode("/", $str)[0]);
    $den = intval(explode("/", $str)[1]);
    return $num/$den;
}
```

*NOTE: I assumed that your strings were fractions, not dates.*

Comment: I would have guessed it was month/day entries.

Comment: Well OP needs to clarify it. But yes, seems like it.

Answer (score 0):

Using usort should work in all cases. It allows us to use a custom function for defining the comparison between array elements. In our custom function we should first convert both elements from fraction to float

```
function cmp ($a, $b) {
    list($num1, $den1) = explode("/", $a);
    list($num2, $den2) = explode("/", $b);

    $a = ($num1/$den1);
    $b = ($num2/$den2);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$classroom = array("4/10","4/2","4/1","4/11","5/2","1/2","5/1","5/10","5/12");

usort($classroom, "cmp");
print_R($classroom);
```